# Auto Populating Cells by Row by Selecting by Value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet called "worlds", and then numerous sheets for various factions for tracking an online game.

Each faction sheet (e.g. "LC", "DC", etc.) has a list of worlds that the faction controls. World's names are entered from Cell I9 downwards. The faction code (LC, DC, etc) is placed in Cell I7.

In the Worlds sheet, each world name is listed in column B (from B2 down) and the controlling faction code is in column E (from E2 down).

What I would like to do is have the faction sheets lookup and list the worlds from the worlds sheet, based on the code in the faction sheet, and cascade down from Cell I9 downwards, without having to manually enter the names.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks for any help that can be provided.
[Faction Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEl6v.png)
[World Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt4YF.png)
[Error for Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea55N.png)

Comment: What you've tried? Maybe a filtered pivot table would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Could you provide a sample file or screenshot about your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Here are screenshots of one faction tab, and the worlds tab. Happy to provide others if you want them. Thanks!

Comment: Added the screen shots to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes it is possible

There are however, a few minor things you'll have to clean-up from Faction to Faction.

If you don't particularly care about how this works, here is the working formula

> =INDEX(Worlds!$B$2:$B$999,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Worlds!$B$2:$B$999)/(Worlds!$E$2:$E$999="LC"),ROW()-8)-1)

1. Replace any instance of $B$999 and $E$999 to however many rows you
   have in total in your World's sheet. If your data only goes down to Row 170, it should be $B$170 and $E$170.
2. Also replace "LC" to any faction you'd like to make the formula work for that instead.
3. Finally change the 8 in ROW()-8 to the number of the row youre starting the formula in -1. If your next faction starts in Row 22, 8 should change to 21.

Now for the explanation

### The Formula Works by Creating a true False Array

> Aggregate(15,

signals that we want to use the Small function. Small will retrieve the smallest value that fits the criteria we want. (Or in this case the first TRUE value)

> Aggregate(15,6

signals that we want to ignore Divide by Zero errors, which will be quite a few.

> Aggregate(15,6,ROW(WORLDS!$B$2:$B$999

Creates a range of numbers 2-Length of our Data Set

> Aggregate(15,6,ROW(WORLDS!$B$2:$B$999)/(Worlds!$E$2:$E$999="LC)

Now we've said we want to divide our number array by a Condition. Worlds E2-E999 is where we have our faction information, we've asked Excel to take all the values in that range and return a TRUE/FALSE. True if the Faction is "LC" False otherwise. This is where a neat trick comes in, EXCEL treats TRUE/FALSE values as 1s and 0s. By dividing our initial number array by 1, we return the number of the row corresponding to any Faction listed as "LC". Otherwise we get a division error. Using Aggregates ability to ignore errors, all that's left to do is to pick the nth smallest value we want.

> Aggregate(15,6,ROW(WORLDS!$B$2:$B$999)/(Worlds!$E$2:$E$999="LC),ROW()-8)

Now we want to pick the first instance of LC in the first spot. Considering that this formula will start in Row 9 on the Factions sheet, we take the current Row using the ROW() function, and subtract 8. This evaluates to ROW()-8 == 9-8 = 1. So we take the 1st smallest value. In this case that will be the first world.

From here we add a basic Index() statement

> INDEX(Worlds!$B$2:$B$999,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Worlds!$B$2:$B$999)/(Worlds!$E$2:$E$999="LC"),ROW()-8)-1)

Index will look up the cell at a given address, we want it to search in $B$2:$B$999 which is where our Worlds are. We also subtract 1 from the value Small returns as an offset because our Worlds don't start in Row 1.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Wow, thanks Snolanda. I have copied the formula into the Cell I9 in the LC sheet and altered the 999 to 3349, as the worlds have 3348 entries. However, the formula stays displayed in the cell and does not return a world name. I assume I am doing something wrong, but can't for the life of me work out what it is.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? :)

Comment: Just added it to the original post. Thanks for helping, I really appreciate it.

Comment: And, what is stranger, is that in a blank sheet the formula works.

Comment: Got it working - don't know how, but changed LC to DC and back again and it worked. You're a legend, that's so much for helping with this, you have made a GM's life a thousandfold easier.

Comment: Glad to help out a fellow Player :) Make sure to mark answered!